# me sale un error name 'limite' is not defined y no se que pasa

Tags: python

Este ejercicio es muy similar al anterior, deseamos una función que calcule la sumatoria de los N primeros números pares.
Sumatoria=2+4+6+8+10+...

```
**def sum_pares (limite):
   cont = 2
   sumatoria=0
  while cont <= limite:  
   sumatoria = sumatoria +cont
   cont+=1
  return sumatoria 
limite_pares=int(input("Ingrese el numero par hasta el que desea realizar la sumatoria: "))
 if limite_pares <= 0:
  print("debe ingresar un número mayor a cero") 
 else:
  **suma_total = sum_pares (limite)** #en esta linea me sale el error 
 print("El valor de la sumatoria es:",suma_total)**
```

Comment: Debes de darle valor al parametro "limite" al llamar la función sum_pares()

Comment: creo que esto `suma_total = sum_pares (limite)` deberia ser `suma_total = sum_pares (limite_pares)`

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que `limite` es una variable que no fue definida, esto quiere decir que no tiene un valor asignado en ningún lado.

Para entender mejor este error que te aparece, hazte la siguiente pregunta "¿qué valor tiene la variable límite que le estoy pasando a la función `sum_pares`?".

Cuando te des cuenta que no tiene ninguno, asígnale uno antes o pásale directamente el valor a la función, por ejemplo: `sum_pares(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

El error es que usastes `limite` en lugar de `limite_pares`.

De paso, es posible acortar el código usando comprensión de listas. Primero generamos una secuencia de pares usando `range` de dos en dos y luego aplicamos la función `sum` sobre la secuencia creada.

```
def sum_pares (limite):
    return sum(i for i in range(2, limite + 1, 2))
```

El resto del programa queda igual, excepto corrigiendo la variable `limite`

```
limite_pares=int(input("Ingrese el numero par hasta el que desea realizar la sumatoria: "))
if limite_pares <= 0:
  print("debe ingresar un número mayor a cero") 
else:
  suma_total = sum_pares (limite_pares)
  print("El valor de la sumatoria es:",suma_total)
```